# python evaluate 2 values to eachother if not none

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to do an evaluation, but only if both values aren't `None`?

```
foo=a
bar=a

if foo==bar:
  pass
```

But I need it as long as foo and bar are not `None`. Basically if both values are None, don't do the evaluation?

Comment: How is this hacky? This just seems like the wrong problem to focus on, almost trivial- i guarantee there are better ways to improve your codebase

Answer (score 2):

Just compare the values to `None` with the `is` operator:

```
if (foo is None) or (bar is None):
    print("skip comparison")
elif condition(foo, bar):
    print("done comparison")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
if not (foo is None and bar is None):
    # do something
```

or by applying de Morgan's Laws:

```
if foo is not None or bar is not None:
    # do something
```

Comment: Or for more fun: `foo is None is bar`